# Leaflet-Draw marker doesn't work properly with custom control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using Leaflet Draw and I've created a custom control instead of the default control.

In my custom control, everything works fine (polylines, polygons, circles and rectangles), except for the marker.
When I click on the Marker menu item, the marker is placed immediately in the position behind the menu, instead of giving me the option to drag it over the map and choose the location (see below wrong vs expected).
[image: wrong]

How can I solve this problem?

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Drawing tools <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="draw('polyline')">Line</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="draw('polygon')">Polygon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="draw('rectangle')">Rectangle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="draw('circle')">Circle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="draw('marker')">Marker</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
function draw(type) {

    var po = '';
    switch(type) {
        case 'polygon':
            po = new L.Draw.Polygon(map);
            break;
        case 'polyline':
            po = new L.Draw.Polyline(map);
            break;
        case 'rectangle':
            po = new L.Draw.Rectangle(map);
            break;
        case 'circle':
            po = new L.Draw.Circle(map);
            break;
        case 'marker':
            po = new L.Draw.Marker(map);
            break;
    }
    po.enable();
}
```

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this with `stopPropagation`:

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Drawing tools <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="draw-tool" data-draw='polyline'>Line</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="draw-tool" data-draw='polygon'>Polygon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="draw-tool" data-draw='rectangle'>Rectangle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="draw-tool" data-draw='circle'>Circle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="draw-tool" data-draw='marker'>Marker</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.draw-tool').click(function(e) {
        var type = $(this).attr('data-draw');
        if (type === 'marker') {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        draw(type);
    })
}); 

function draw(type) {

    var po = '';
    switch(type) {
        case 'polygon':
            po = new L.Draw.Polygon(map);
            break;
        case 'polyline':
            po = new L.Draw.Polyline(map);
            break;
        case 'rectangle':
            po = new L.Draw.Rectangle(map);
            break;
        case 'circle':
            po = new L.Draw.Circle(map);
            break;
        case 'marker':
            po = new L.Draw.Marker(map);
            break;
    }
    po.enable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following for the Marker

```
po = new L.Draw.Marker(map, { draggable : true});
```